# Dynamically adding an associative multidimensional array to an array containing another associative multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to dynamically generate an multidimensional array where the `$value` of the `$key=>$value` pairs is another multidimensional array. The keys are going to generate dynamically through a select menu (which itself is dynamically generated, so I wont know the names of keys).

It's for a WordPress plugin so there are some WP functions in the following code:

```
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
if (get_option('option_name') != null) {
     $option = get_option('option_name');
     $option[$var2] = array('sync'=>1,'setting1'=>$var2,'setting2'=>$var1);
     update_option('option_name', $option[$var2]);

} else {
    $option = array();
    $option[$var2] = array('sync'=>1,'setting1'=>$var2,'setting2'=>$var1);
    update_option('option_name', $option[$var2]);
}
```

Basically, the "else" part of this, indicating that get_option('option_name') is empty or not set, is working great and after the update_option function is called I get:

```
Array
    (
        [firstvar2] => Array
            (
                [sync] => 1
                [setting1] => firstvar2
                [setting2] => firstvar1
            )

    )
```

Which is exactly what I want. The problem I am having is adding an additional associative array when this first one is already present. The 'if' part of the conditional is giving me this:

```
Array
    (
        [sync] => 1
        [setting1] => firstvar2 //(from the first run)
        [setting2] => firstvar1 //(from the first run)
        [secondvar2] => Array //(from the second run)
            (
                [sync] => 1
                [setting1] => secondvar2 //(from the second run)
                [setting2] => secondvar1 //(from the second run)
            )

    )
```

How can I get this instead?:

```
Array
    (
        [firstvar2] => Array //first run
            (
                [sync] => 1 //first run
                [setting1] => firstvar2 //first run
                [setting2] => firstvar1 //first run
            )

        [secondvar2] => Array //second run
            (
                [sync] => 1 //second run
                [setting1] => secondvar2 //second run
                [setting2] => secondvar1 //second run
            )

    )
```

Comment: You cannot as you cannot have 2 Associative KEYS with the same value. It makes no sence

Comment: They don't have the same value. I just used as placeholders. Its whatever the $_POST variable is. I'll edit so its less confusing

Comment: What is `update_option()`?

Comment: A WordPress function. I mentioned that already. It just replaces what is located in get_option('option_name') with the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should update all of the $option `update_option( 'option_name', $option );`
what is happening is basically your always setting $option equal to `$option[ $var2 ]`

Comment: Of course! Thank you, I knew it must have been a simple error.

Comment: Also bonus thanks. Because now I also don't need the complex conditional. Just the following works: $option = get_option('option_name');
     $option[$var2] = array('sync'=>1,'setting1'=>$var2,'setting2'=>$var1);
     update_option('option_name', $option);

Comment: sure no problem. and yes you can simply get_option() ? get_option() : array(), and don't forget to check if its an array, since it can get you in trouble as well :)